# Accessing Google Calendar Events with MS Access Database

Tags: vba, google-api, google-calendar-api

I wrote an access database several years ago that used VBA to pull events from my Google calendar and present them on a report. It worked great for a couple of years but then Google must have made a change and it stopped working. I didn't have time to figure it out at the time so I let it go but now I would like to see if I can get my app working again. I've been Googling all morning trying to figure this out but I'm just not finding anything that's helpful. I've looked thru the Google API website but it doesn't address VBA so I'm wondering if it's no longer supported???

So my question: is it still possible to retrieve Google calendar data from MS Access using VBA? If so, can anyone point me towards resources that explain how to do it?

Thanks for any help,
Chris

Comment: Perhaps start with the code you originally used? You should be able to use whatever resources are available in VBA to remotely query URLs to access the Calendar REST API. Note that [the only authorization allowed is via OAuth2.](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post the code you have.  Also, consider recording a Macro in Excel, and modify it slightly to work in Access.  The Macro Recorder can generate a lot of code for you (actually, you will probably end up with too much code).  You can't record a Macro using Access, but the Excel object model and the Access object model are very similar.